# Method not allowed — removing Access-Control-Request-Method from request headers in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm currently trying a `DELETE` type of request with Angular `ngResource` on a Restful API located on another domain.
`GET` and `PUT` work fine.
**`DELETE` works in the Advanced Rest Client Chrome extension but doesn't work when tried with Angular `$resource`.**

I have noticed a difference in the headers sent, which are these two:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:DELETE
```

When I try to add these two headers in Advanced Rest Client I get the following errors in the Chrome console:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers"
Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"
```

Finally the server (which is normally configured to accept cross-domain requests), when I try the `DELETE` request with Angular, sends the following response (with status `200` and method use `OPTIONS`):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:PUT,DELETE
Cache-Control:private, must-revalidate
Connection:close
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 12 Feb 2015 12:08:47 GMT
ETag:"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
Server:Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8o DAV/2 PHP/5.5.20
```

But I get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [URL]. Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
```

**I suspect the first mentioned two headers to be the cause of the problem. Are they the problem and if yes how could I remove them?**

---

If it can help, I tried configuring my `$httpProvider` (as seen in other questions/answers) and it currently looks like this:

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Request-Method'];
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Request-Headers'];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server should set **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** header for response instead of **Allow** header like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT,DELETE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify you suggest that the server should be configured using `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT,DELETE` instead of the current  `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*`

Comment: Oh I see, can you please specify, which server are you using? And the server side code where you are setting the headers.

Comment: I don't have direct access to it but they use an Apache Server and the Headers are currently set via .htaccess

Comment: Ok, explicitly replacing `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"` by `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"` in the .htaccess solved the problem, thank you!